# Converting dbase do while to sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dbase

I wrote a dBase procedure and I'm having a hard time converting it to a SQL Server stored procedure.

This is what I have for dbase:

```
CLOSE ALL

SELECT A
USE DDCS_OLD

SELECT B
USE CROSSELL

DO WHILE .NOT. EOF()
mLAT1 = IND_LAT
mLONG1 = IND_LONG

IF mLAT1 > 0 .AND. mLONG1 < 0

SELECT A
GOTO TOP
DO WHILE .NOT. EOF()

  mLAT2 = LAT
  mLONG2 = LONG
  mPROP_CODE = PROP_CODE

  mDISTANCE = 3963.0 * ACOS(SIN(mLAT1/57.2958) * SIN(mLAT2/57.2958) + COS(mLAT1/57.2958) * COS(mLAT2/57.2958) * COS(mLONG2/57.2958 - mLONG1/57.2958))

  SELECT B
  REPLACE &mPROP_CODE WITH mDISTANCE
  SELECT A
  SKIP
  ENDDO

ENDIF

SELECT B
SKIP
```

END DO'

I have never written a stored procedure before so I'm not sure how to go about a do while loop while using the two tables `ddcs_old` and `crossell`.

Comment: You need to add the table structures, sample data, expected result and a description of what your code does. And in the description you should specially mention what "magic" `&mPROP_CODE` does for you.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a tremendously complicated calculation that I would consider moving out of the database and into the application that is using this data, if at all possible.

However, I'm guessing that what DO WHILE .NOT. EOF() does in dbase is basically read one row at a time from the table, until it reaches the end. In a SQL Stored Procedure you would achieve this with a cursor:

```
DECLARE crDDCS_Old CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT LAT, LONG, PROP_CODE FROM ddcs_old

OPEN crDDCS_Old
FETCH NEXT FROM crDDCS_Old

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Do your calculations here
    FETCH NEXT FROM crDDCS_Old
END

CLOSE crDDCS_Old
DEALLOCATE crDDCS_Old
```

As I said, I would strongly recommend reconsidering the best way of implementing this functionality, a direct conversion to a stored procedure is highly unlikely to be the best approach. Cursors are inefficient and, apparently, more lines of code than the dbase equivalent. You'd need in-depth knowledge of what it was doing in dbase and how that data is being used, to come up with the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use sql like DBase. If at all possible, you want to execute any operation using a set based operation that update all corresponding rows with a single update command -- I.e., you avoid loops based on a cursor 99.97% of the time. Also, without column definitions for your DBase tables (and hopefully corresponding columns for your SQL tables), I don't know how you expect to get any help as it is not really possible to figure out what your existing code does.

However it also looks a like you you are doing great circle calculations, beginning in Sql 2008, you can use the geography data type, which has build in functions for a number of geographic features, including great circle distances.

You really need to get a little understanding of how SQL works instead of asking for some magic and opaque answer -- the time will be well spent and when you get stuck, S/O is a good source for getting unstuck.

I know this is more of a comment, but it is too long for a comment.